Data analysis migration (user experience)
I have a challenge with databases, since we are currently working with Excel macros to carry out processes
Users interact friendly with the database, changing rows, adding data, etc.
We want to migrate to languages ​​and platforms that, on the one hand, are more efficient and allow us to process the data in a better way, in ingestion and filtering and that automate the processing, so that the user does not have to enter to run the database, but rather does so. on a scheduled basis
We were thinking of migrating to the use of pandas in python, but the user experience on this platform is not as visual or friendly as excel, and requires training, which is not an option.
Could you recommend platforms, languages, power apps, or any tool that meets this goal?

As you said in your question I would go for:

FileMaker
Power Apps

...or any other alternatives, there are a few out there and I also find a chart to compare them.
You basically have to create an interface for your employees.
I would try all the 10 here in the list and see if there is any interface that is suitable for you and that comes out-of-the-box.
